# Mockito - Spring Mvc Service test (Null pointer)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm new to Testing side.I'm using Spring Mvc in my application. I followed some tutorials to write for controller and service Test Case. I'm facing error in service test. Please help !

Service :

```
@Autowired
private PatientDao patientDao;

@Autowired
private PrefixDao prefixDao;

public Patient createPatient(Patient patient) throws Exception {
    patient.setAgeorDob();
    return createPatientInSync(patient);
}

private synchronized Patient createPatientInSync(Patient patient)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            Prefix prefix = prefixDao.getPrefixForType(PrefixType.PATIENT);
            patient.setPatientNo(prefix.getPrefixedNumber());
            patientDao.createPatient(patient); //SAVE PATIENT
            prefixDao.incrementPrefix(prefix);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            throw new InternalErrorException("Please enter valid data", ex);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new InternalErrorException(
                    "Please create Prefix for Patient", e);
        }
        return patient;
    }
```

Service Test case:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml",
        "classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml",
        "classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml",
        "classpath:/applicationContext.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PatientServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Mock
    private PatientDao patientDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private PatientServiceImpl patientService = new PatientServiceImpl();

    private PrefixDao prefixDao;


    @Before
    public void doSetup() {
        patientDao = mock(PatientDao.class);
        prefixDao = mock(PrefixDao.class);
        // Mockito.mock(PatientDao.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveUser() throws Exception {

        Patient mockPatient = new Patient();
        mockPatient.setFirstName("Aravinth");
        mockPatient.setSex(Gender.Male);
        mockPatient.setAgeOrDob("24");

        Prefix prefix = new Prefix();
        prefix.setPrefixType(PrefixType.PATIENT);
        prefix.setPrefix("Pat-");
        prefix.setSequenceNo(23);

        when(prefixDao.getPrefixForType(PrefixType.PATIENT)).thenReturn(prefix);
        System.out.println(prefix.getSequenceNo());

        mockPatient = patientService.createPatient(mockPatient);

        assertEquals("Aravinth", mockPatient.getFirstName()); 

        verify(patientDao, times(1)).createPatient(mockPatient);
    }
}
```

Verify times works fine.I got Nullpointer in assertEquals.

Comment: Check in your patientDao instance, when createPatient called, it return null.

Comment: updated my dao code.. @PupCode

Comment: you're not right, your dao is a Mock Object, so it don't run your actually code ... and i see in the doc this instruction to put in before annotation :
    ´MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);´

Comment: Hi pup. same error :-(  share any example link

Comment: to you service : http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mock.html

Comment: You are mixing things up: By supplying a context configuration and running the test with the Spring runner, you basically indicate the test is an integration test, where you want to test all the different objects involved in a certain method call. On the Other hand you have the annotation @Mock on your DAO which suggests, you want all method calls of the DAO to be mocked. So what exactly are you trying to test here?

Comment: @hotzst I tried to write Integration test. my test includes for Both Prefix and Patient.I'm new to testing. suggest some examples,it would help me.

Comment: For getting familar with Mockito take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html). From taking a closer look at you test code I notice two things: 1. you are not calling the `PatientSeriveImpl` you probably wanted to test in the first place and 2. verifying the number of calls to `createPatient` here is useless, as the only call is from your code.

Comment: Tnx !! yeah! you are correct .. see my updated code, it works

Answer (score 0):

Need to @Mock PrefixDao first.
If you are using Junit 5, no need to run initMocks(this). Otherwise you need this: MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
With that, the mockito will wire two mock Dao objects to your service.

Also I don't see you mock action for patientDao.
When(patientDao.create()).thenReturn(...);